# How to use the conformal property of bilinear transform to show that the left half plane is mapped to the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

[image]

Intuitively, conformal means angle preserving. How can I see that the left half plane is mapped to the unit disc with the angle of each element of the left half plane preserved?

Comment: you are using the term bilinear incorrectly. Consider reading your textbook.

Comment: I bet he just used "bilinear" in place of "biolomorphic". Anyway, this is a duplicate.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think "bilinear" here stands for "fractional linear", $(az+b)/(cz+d)$. Because there are two linear functions in the formula.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I think 'pizza' has hit it exactly. This is traditionally called a *linear fractional mapping* or a *fractional linear mapping*.